# in-place coalescing like elements in a std::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, std

I have an array of pairs, for example:

```
X = {{A, 1}, {B, 2}, {C, 1}, {A, 3}, {C, 4}}
```

I would like to produce an array:

```
Y = (x, n) such that n = sum i for (x, i) in X
```

so in the example above, we'd have:

```
Y = {{A, 4}, {B, 2}, {C, 5}}
```

The code I currently have is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char A = 'A';
    char B = 'B';
    char C = 'C'; 

    vector< pair<char, int> > X = {{A, 1}, {B, 2}, {C, 1}, {A, 3}, {C, 4}};

    // Sort by first element of the pair
    sort(begin(X), end(X), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.first < b.first; });

    // Could this be better? Is there an existing STL algorithm that will
    // do this in-place?
    vector< pair<char, int> > Y;
    for(auto p : X) {
        if(Y.empty() || Y.back().first != p.first) {
            Y.push_back(p);
        } else {
            Y.back().second += p.second;
        }
    }

    cout << "Y:";
    for (auto p : Y) {
       cout << '{' << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '}';
    }
    cout << '\n';

}
```

*Could this code be made more succinct?* (Without changing the type of the underlying container)

I'm looking to try to eliminate the [raw loop](https://youtu.be/qH6sSOr-yk8?t=130), by replacing with an algorithm in the standard library, but I don't see one that would quite fit.

I'd want some variant of `std::unique` which takes not only a predicate for whether two elements are equivalent, but also a function which defines how to combine them. It might look like:

```
coalesce(begin(X), end(X), [](auto a, auto b){ return a.first == b.first; }, [](auto a, auto b) { return {a.first, a.second+b.second} });
```

FWIW, here's an implementation of `coalesce` which seems to work:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicate, class BinaryFunction>
ForwardIt coalesce(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicate p, BinaryFunction f)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    ForwardIt result = first;
    while (++first != last) {
        if(p(*result, *first)) {
            *result = f(*result, *first);
        } else {
            ++result;
            *result = *first;
        }
    }
    return ++result;
}
```

And the code becomes:

```
    vector< pair<char, int> > X = {{A, 1}, {B, 2}, {C, 1}, {A, 3}, {C, 4}};

    // Sort by first element of the pair
    sort(begin(X), end(X), [](auto a, auto b) { return a.first < b.first; });

    // Easier to understand the intent!
    auto e = coalesce(begin(X), end(X),
                      [](auto a, auto b) { return a.first == b.first; },
                      [](auto a, auto b) { return pair<char, int>{a.first, a.second+b.second}; });

    for_each(begin(X), e, [](auto p) {
        cout << '{' << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '}';
    });
    cout << '\n';
```

NOTE: I'm quite familiar with `map`, etc, and don't want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, an approach that uses no other containers, with no raw loops (or `std::for_each`) might combine `std::sort` with [`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum)

`std::partial_sum` is for computing prefix sums, or rather a generic way to combine adjacent elements. After our initial sort, we can use `std::partial_sum` to combine elements with the same key:

```
std::vector< std::pair<char, int> > Y;
std::vector< std::pair<char, int> > Y(X.size());
std::partial_sum(X.begin(), X.end(),  Y.rbegin(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.first != rhs.first)
        return rhs;
    return std::make_pair(lhs.first, lhs.second + rhs.second);
});
```

Notice that we iterate backwards in `Y`. This is intentional for the next step, which I'll elaborate shortly.

This gets us part of the way there. Now we have a `Y` that looks like this:

```
Y:{C 5}{C 1}{B 2}{A 4}{A 1}
```

Now our task is to remove the duplicates, which we can do with [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique):

```
Y.erase(std::unique(Y.begin(), Y.end(), 
   [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){
      return lhs.first == rhs.first;}), Y.end());
```

We needed to use `partial_sum` over the reversed range, because `std::unique` "Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements", and we needed the final `partial_sum` to appear first.

The total algorithm is O(N log N) on account of the sorting. Memory usage is O(N).

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xOCsZ8CcAqfaTQXC)

Answer (score 3):

I'd be tempted to define it in terms of a [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), not equals. You'd `std::upper_bound` to get groups and `std::accumulate` within each group.

```
template<class ForwardIt, class OutputIt, class Compare = std::less<>, class BinaryOperation = std::plus<>>
OutputIt coalesce(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, OutputIt d_first, Compare comp = {}, BinaryOperation op = {})
{
    while (first != last) {
        ForwardIt group = std::upper_bound(first, last, *first, comp);
        *d_first++ = std::accumulate(std::next(first), group, *first, op);
        first = group;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Which would be used like

```
vector< pair<char, int> > X = {{'A', 1}, {'B', 2}, {'C', 1}, {'A', 3}, {'C', 4}};
less<> comp;
auto add = [](auto a, auto b) { return pair<char, int>{a.first, a.second+b.second}; };

sort(begin(X), end(X)/*, comp*/);

auto e = coalesce(begin(X), end(X), begin(X), comp, add);
X.erase(e, end(X));

for (auto [k, v] : X) {
    cout << '{' << k << ' ' << v << '}';
}
```

Comment: `comp` is actually not needed in `sort(begin(x), end(x)` (although it's probably slightly more efficient)

Comment: @AndyG not in this exact case, but OP used it in their sort call

Answer (score 2):

(Note: OP edited the question after my answer to specify they didn't want to use a `map` or its variations, and then again to specify it needed to be in-place)

A hash table will do the coalescing work for you:

```
std::unordered_map<char, int> coalesced;
for(const auto key_val : X)
    coalesced[key_val.first] += key_val.second;
```

Now we have a hash table with contents of

```
A : 4
B : 2
C : 5
```

If you want to put that into another `std::vector`, that's fine:

```
vector< pair<char, int> > Y(coalesced.begin(), coalesced.end());
```

Or you could leave as-is.

The `unordered_map` is unsorted w.r.t keys (hence the "unordered" name). If you want them ordered, then you can just use a `std::map` exactly the same way (but it's implemented as a binary search tree rather than a hash table)

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Z0eMCF9R1Sd0yXwg)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a raw loop, especially a one liner like that. If you so desire, you can use `std::for_each` instead. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P3ROOXGCEja80CSO)

Comment: `std::unique` eliminates copies on a sorted vector. This is much different than what a hash table does. Using a hash table also eliminates your need for an initial sort of `X`. Granted, the memory usage is doubled due to the extra container.

Comment: No worries, sorry for the escalation. If an answer doesn't fit the question, why not remove it? Is this about having good answers to a given question, or scoring points?

Comment: @Taylor: The answer answered the question as-was, and I think that it's useful for future visitors without the same constraints as you. In the future, please ask a new question instead of editing the old one to make existing answers invalid.